# Write a script that runs a command with arguments

Tags: python, windows

How can I write a script in Windows that runs the following command?

```
autoflake -i -r --remove-all-unused-imports %file_directory%
```

My script looks like this:

```
file_directory = input("Enter directory name to run autoflake: ")

def autoflake_run():
    try:
        # I would like to run the command here.
    except:
        print("Path file error. Please make sure directory exists.")


autoflake_run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess).

```
import subprocess

file_directory = input('Enter directory name to run autoflake: ')


def autoflake_run():
    try:
        subprocess.run('autoflake -i -r --remove-all-unused-imports {}'
                       .format(file_directory))
    except:
        print('Path file error. Please make sure directory exists.')

autoflake_run()
```